# Windows 8 Winrt Application goes to background or close

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, lifecycle

How can you tell when a windows 8 Metro app gets put in the background? The suspended state doesn't activate. I have a break point on. It only hits if I close the app.

I am using a webcam and since no apps can run in the background I need to save my work when it's put in the background.

The windows phone it was application deactivated.

any help would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apps do not normally get suspended when in the debugger. However, you can force a suspend *when debugging* by:

1. Enabling the Debug Location toolbar (red arrow in image below).
2. Then press the Suspend button (blue arrow).

[image: suspend]

Answer (score 1):

The suspending event should fire when the application is no longer active, namely, when another application is brought to the front.  Presuming you're using C#/XAML, the app.xaml.cs file already has the [Suspending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx) event wired up.  In HTML5/JavaScript it's [checkpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229839.aspx) and you'll see it in default.js.

Comment: Suspend doesn't fire. I have a break point on. It only hits if I close the app.