# WinRT How to Test and simulate Suspension States

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I search a possibility to test the suspension behavior of my app.

Is there a way to force suspension for a windows 8 / WinRT C# app?

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14077958/1822514

Comment: Many thanks thats the solution I don't know why but I didn't find it before :-)