# How to detect when Windows 8 goes to sleep or resumes

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, lifecycle

I have an app that keeps a connection alive to a server, however if the user walks away and the tablet goes to sleep, I would like to handle the disconnect gracefully, and I would also like to log back in when the user wakes the tablet.

I've tried in my putting the following code in my connection class, but they never get fired.

```
Application.Current.Suspending += this.OnAppSuspending;
Application.Current.Resuming += this.OnAppResuming;;
```

Comment: If you have the debugger open, this question may explain things: [Windows 8 Winrt Application goes to background or close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076188/windows-8-winrt-application-goes-to-background-or-close)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For desktop apps, you can use [SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx) event to know if Windows is going into sleep state. I don't know if this works for the tablets too, but you can try it...

From MSDN:

• Resume The operating system is about to resume from a suspended state.

• StatusChange A power mode status notification event has been raised by the operating system. This might indicate a weak or charging battery, a transition between AC power and battery, or another change in the status of the system power supply.

• Suspend The operating system is about to be suspended.

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;

private void OnPowerChange(object s, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    switch ( e.Mode ) 
    {
        case PowerModes.Resume: 
        break;
        case PowerModes.Suspend:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't find this api in my windows 10 uwp app. any ideas?

Comment: @ Joris Weimar did you find any solutions?

Comment: Works like charm.!