# Windows 10 Sleep Issue. Graphics disappearing

Tags: c#, windows, hibernate, xaml, windows-10

I have a Windows UWP C#/XAML app that has a strange issue. When the display goes to sleep and I wake the computer up, some button graphics disappear. I have a Windows 8 app that exhibits the same behavior on Windows 10, but not on Windows 8. I want to try to build a workaround that refreshes UI elements upon waking from a sleep but I'm having a hard time finding a trigger. I've heard about this [PowerModeChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256664/how-to-detect-when-windows-8-goes-to-sleep-or-resumes) but I cannot find this API somehow. Any ideas?

[image: SystemEvents not found]

Comment: `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;`? Visual Studio will likely find the right using for it if you just right click it.

Comment: See updated question. The API is not available. I already added the Desktop Extensions for UWP but still no luck.

Comment: @VoidStar I think this event is not available for Windows UWP Apps... At least not in this form.

Comment: @AlexH any idea in what form it is?

Comment: @JorisWeimar I'm sorry, the half time i do something with Windows Apps i'm searching for these kind of stuff... When i find something i will post it.

Comment: @JorisWeimar Can you try and check for suspending? I think the App could get suspended while windows sleeps. And there are ways to check for it.

Comment: @AlexH unfortunately the resume is not called when the computer wakes up... (or suspend)

Comment: Did anyone found an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: are you experiencing the same issue? the solution i used was adding ?1 to the duplicate images. also, there was some issues with sound streams disappearing. i used an idle detection system for that. if the system had been idle for > 10 seconds and the user would access the stream, it would reload first. not exactly elegant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to add the answer that relates to the original problem in my question: the disappearing of the graphics.

I had multiple Image elements with that had the same Source URI (pointing to same image). One of them was hidden, the other one wasn't. Somehow this caused the images to disappear altogether. Must be something about how XAML handles referencing Images especially after a suspend/awake. I added ?1 to one of the image URI's and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If the API is not available you could try to refresh the UI based on mouse/keyboard activity after being idle for certain time, if that works, you need to have the idle equal to time needed for computer to sleep, another you could also try is catching the activated event on your own app in case it fires after sleep.

Comment: activated event is not being called. i've thought about the mouse/keyboard activity "hack", but that seems very ugly. if you move your mouse to wake up your keyboard, the graphics would be missing until the mouse is moved or keyboard is tapped. thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: ok, i guess if there is an API support issue with "Windows UWP" Apps, one thing you could try is to create a separate app in a form of a background service or background process using a different type of project that would have access to the API's that you need and communicate with it from your UWP app to perform the action needed.

I never tried this personally but i would it guess it might be possible.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a separate app, many apps work in both user application and background service, you could probably create this as a class library project inside your project and then deploy it as a service to the user's system either using your app itself or separately. If you do this through your app you will have control over it and users won't have to go through the installation of another app.

Comment: ah, i see. i went with an idle detection system. thanks.