# Does debugger prevent suspension?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

When my windows store app goes to the background it still keeps running.

According to the [documentation of the App.Suspend event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#app_suspend) the app should suspend after a few seconds when in background.

I tried running the app on a simulator and on a real device, both with a debugger attached.

Is the debugger preventing the app from suspension? Or am I mistaken that the app suspends after a few seconds when it is in the background?

Comment: Yes, debugging the app would be quite difficult if it didn't.  Skip to 15:00 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEE6ojR3nWs&feature=youtu.be&t=14ms34)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 Winrt Application goes to background or close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076188/windows-8-winrt-application-goes-to-background-or-close)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the debugger prevents suspension. In Visual Studio, however, you can force suspend, resume, and suspend+terminate. There's a dropdown on the toolbar for this purpose when you're running the app, which lets you trigger background tasks for debugging as well.